# Obtener ruta de un archivo dentro de mi proyecto

Tags: java

Cómo puedo obtener la ruta del archivo text.txt que está dentro de mi proyecto?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy intentando esto pero no me funciona:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\App\\src\\text.txt"));
Desktop.getDesktop().browse(URI.create(reader.readLine()));
reader.close();
```

Comment: Prueba si [esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/162801) te sirve. ;)

Answer (score 0):

cuando usas la función `System.getProperty("user.dir")` no es necesario que especifiques el nombre de la carpeta del proyecto ya que eso lo hace solo el `"user.dir"`  bastaria con solo poner

```
System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src\\text.txt"
```